# Identify the soundtrack of "What I Like About You" S04E06

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

Does anybody know what is the title of the song played in TV series *What I Like About You*, starring Amanda Bynes, in the episode [*Halloween*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0746049/) S04E06?

It starts playing when Holly & Vince are sleeping and Holly wakes up and looks at him and realizes she's ready for him. The lyrics go something like this:

> what does it mean, cause it seems when we fall in love, losing all control and you don't know what to do when it's true every direction...

Comment: [Welcome to Music Fans Stack Exchange](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour). Here you can learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for get accurate answers. I hope that the currents answers match with you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

After a quick search, I found it is [*Love Grabs You* by Avner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUErYJbyjVQ). The lyrics match what you said.